# Change PasswordToggle Gravity to the left (for RTL language)

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I use `TextInputLayout` to get password from user like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/RegisterPassInput"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/RegisterPassImg">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/RegisterPassET"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:hint="@string/Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLength="40" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and the result is:

[image]

But i want something like this:

[image]

How can i set passwordToggle gravity align left of the editText.
For lots of reasons I disabled `rtl` support in *manifest*

```
android:supportsRtl="false"
```

Comment: you want to align text to left ?

Comment: @Swarnveer no, i want the passwordToggle icon goes to the left.

Comment: From the above xml code there is no password toggle icon. Please update your XML in the question

Comment: @Swarnveer as you see there is  `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"` in my TextInputLayout which create this icon and toggle behavioral.

Answer (score 7):

In your `TextInputLayout`, add this argument:

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

**Edit:**
for API < 17 (Using `android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat`):

```
TextInputLayout inputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.RegisterPassInput); 
ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(inputLayout, ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Comment: thanks but not working and it says: Attribute layoutDirection is only used in API level 17 and higher (current min is 9).

Comment: I edited my answer for API < 17 - you can use the Support Library and it will work. Other option you have is to change the minSdk (in gradle) to 17 if your not developing for devices with lower API.

Comment: vote up for your answer, but in my case for lots of reasons i set `android:supportsRtl="false"` in manifest.