# How to move toggle password button to left side?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-method

I'm using toggle password in my form, this is my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
       android:id="@+id/input_layout_pass"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="37dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       app:hintEnabled="false"
       app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

       <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            style="@style/edittexts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_pass"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

it works fine and shows the toggle button view in my EditText .

I just want to move the icon to the left side of edit text , How can I do so ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change PasswordToggle Gravity to the left (for RTL language)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968840/change-passwordtoggle-gravity-to-the-left-for-rtl-language)

Answer (score 4):

You need to change direction of edit text, but it will change your direction of edit text it will start writing right to left.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
   android:id="@+id/input_layout_pass"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="37dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
   android:layoutDirection="rtl"
   app:hintEnabled="false"
   app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        style="@style/edittexts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_pass"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

also if you are using api version below 17 you need to add this attribute in your code

```
TextInputLayout input_layout_pass = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_pass); 
ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(input_layout_pass, ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the docs for [`TextInputLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html):

> Note: When using the password toggle functionality, the 'end' compound drawable of the EditText will be overridden while the toggle is enabled. To ensure that any existing drawables are restored correctly, you should set those compound drawables relatively (start/end), opposed to absolutely (left/right).

Based on this, you see that you can't change the position of the button without changing the text orientation in that field.

Comment: Well, it doesn't have to work. Basically you can't change the position of that button (and keeping the direction from left to right) without using your custom layout.